# Integrating a function with Max function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate the triple integral
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} \int_{0}^{1-\max(x,y)}1 dzdydx$$

in Mathematica. The code I'm using is simply

```
Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[1,{z,0,Max[x,y]}],{y,0,1-x}],{x,0,1}]
```

Mathematica thinks for a second and then gives as an output

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x}1-\max(x,y)dydx.$$

I thought that Mathematica would be able to handle this type of integral because when I evaluate this in wolfram alpha, I get the correct answer of $\frac{1}{4}$.

I don't need to get the exact value of the integral, just correct to a few decimal places would be nice. Eventually, I'm hoping to integrate a few slightly more complicated functions that have maximums and minimums of the variables in them.

Comment: Try `Integrate[1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, {z, 0, Max[x, y]}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the multiple integral syntax instead of nesting [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate):

```
Integrate[1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1-x}, {z, 0, Max[x, y]}]
```

> 1/4

Comment: Wonderful. I knew there must be a simple solution I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is as follows.

```
Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[1,{z, 0, Max[x, y]},Assumptions -> x >= 0&&x<= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1],
 {y, 0, 1 - x}, Assumptions -> x >= 0&& x <= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> 1/4

Compare

```
Integrate[Integrate[1, {z, 0, Max[x, y]}, 
 Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x <= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1], {y, 0, 1 - x},
Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x <= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{2} (1-2 x) & x=0 \\
>  -(x-1) x & \frac{1}{2}\leq x<1 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} \left(2 x^2-2 x+1\right) & 0<x<\frac{1}{2}
> \end{cases} $$

with

```
Integrate[Integrate[1, {z, 0, Max[x, y]}], {y, 0, 1 - x}]
```

> $\int_0^{1-x} \max (x,y) \, dy .$